# How to Dynamically Build Checkboxes based on a SQL Report

Tags: sql, checkbox, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Using Oracle APEX v4.2.2, I would like to dynamically build a checkbox selection list based on data from an Oracle Classic Report.

For example:

```
Location          Dept A.     Dept. B     Dept. C      Total Employees
----------------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
Paris             5           10          3            18
```

Using the above report, I would like to dynamically build three checkboxes based on the columns Dept. A, Dept. B and Dept. C

So beneath my report I would expect to see checkboxes:

`[]Dept. A  []Dept. B  []Dept. C`

Obviously if my report only returned just Dept. A then I would expect to see just one checkbox:

`[]Dept. A`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it:

1) If the number of checkboxes are (a) known and (b) small, you can create each checkbox and make it conditional on an associated hidden page item (say :PXX_DEPTA_COUNT). Then you can have each of those hidden items either their value using 'Always / SQL Query', or they can be set all at once via a Page Process.

2) You can also create a PL/SQL dynamic content region, and use the apex.item API to create the checkboxes: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_item.htm#AEAPI1006

If you go with the dynamic content region, you're going to have to do the HTML work yourself, but you can cheat by first creating a test region with some checkboxes laid out the way you want, then look at the page source and use the same HTML in your dynamic region.